# How to make query on another query result in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a query like that to get result by joining 3 tables

## QUERY 1

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.nick_id, count(b.invoice_id) AS INVOICES, sum(b.purchase_amount) AS PURCHASES, c.sponsor_id, c.user_first_name, c.user_last_name

FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.user_id = c.user_id

WHERE b.purchase_date BETWEEN '2018-09-01 00:00:00' AND now() and a.user_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY a.user_id ORDER BY PURCHASES DESC
```

### Table1 (Example)

```
user_id | nick_id

1 | AGENT1

2 | AGENT2

3 | AGENT3
```

### Table2 (Example)

```
user_id | invoice_id | purchase_amount | purchase_date

1 | IN001 | 500 | 2018-09-01 14:58:33

2 | IN002 | 1000 | 2018-09-18 22:46:12
```

### Table3 (Example)

```
user_id | sponsor_id | user_first_name | user_last_name

2 | 1 | John | Doe

3 | 1 | Harry | Wilson

4 | 2 | Peter | Bennington

5 | 2 | Daisy | Cooper
```

Now on the result of [QUERY 1], I want to perform [QUERY 2]

## QUERY 2

```
SELECT  sponsor_id, user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name
FROM
(SELECT * FROM table3 ORDER BY sponsor_id, user_id) table3,
(SELECT @pv := '1') initialisation WHERE find_in_set(sponsor_id, @pv) > 0
AND @pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_id)
```

After that I will get my desired result. But I want to perform both queries at once in a single query.

Comment: It's always nice to know what you are trying to achieve as well as how you are trying to achieve it,and expected output would be useful.

Comment: If you made the first query into a `view` than you can treat it exactly the same as 'table' in other queries. The `view` allows you to easily test it.